# SharePoint via ADFS - Ant SharePoint Functionality Impacted

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, adfs, 2016, federation

We are exploring federating our on-premise SharePoint instance via ADFS -- there are many excellent technical SharePoint/ADFS guides available.

Is there a list of SharePoint functionality that may be lost if a user accesses via ADFS instead of via Active Directory?

Some thoughts: network drive mapping may not be available.

Comment: what SharePoint version we are talking about here?

Comment: SharePoint 2016 (apologies  -- i should have listed that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couples of things which I experienced.

- You have to write a custom claims provider in order to properly add users, without it Sharepoint except everything you typed in people picker.
- You need an NTLM authentication in default Zone for the search crawling.Search crawler is not aware of saml claims.

  - if default zone with both authentication( NTLM & ADFS) then chances are user can set permission using ADFS & NT credential.But with custom claims provider you can restrict it.
  - If default zone with NTLM and extended with ADFS, then there are issues with Alerts Because Alerts Use the default zone URL.

Also

- Search service will experience a lot of issues with ADFS crawling.
- You will use Active Directory Import for User profile, which also has a limitation as compared to User Profile Sync.
- Unable to Trust a Workflows that required Tenant Admin rights( another limitation of Saml).

  - few of EE services are not Samls compatible i.e Visio, powerPivot, SQL SR

Comment: Would it be same with 2013?

Comment: There is no improvement in 2016 so far, these will be same in 2013